# How to align both vertically and horizontally in CSS?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a box like this:

```
<section class="notes-list-box">
    <div class="nn">
        <div class="heading">Notes</div>
        <div class="boxdescription">With our complete study notes, your homework is much easier.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ttn">
        <div class="heading">Things To Know</div>
        <div class="boxdescription">Things to know provides additional information on every topic which enhance the knowledge of  the students.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="vdos">
        <div class="heading">Videos</div>
        <div class="boxdescription">Reference videos on each topic provides experimental ideas and develops interactive learning technique.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sqaa">
        <div class="heading">Solved Question and Answer</div>
        <div class="boxdescription">With 100's of solved questions solved, now you can easily prepare your exam for free.</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Adding little bit of styling make it looks like this:

[image]

I have tried using `vertical-align` like this:

```
.notes-list-box > div {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

and it works. But I don't know how to `align vertical at bottom` so that all the white space also comes to bottom.

So the white space below notes and solved question and answer `white background` comes till bottom.

I want to fill those gaps with white space:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

I used this CSS:

```
.notes-list-box {
  display: flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.notes-list-box > div {
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: white;
}
.heading {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
.boxdescription {
  padding: 5px;
}
.nn .heading {
  background-color: #61B5DF;
}
.ttn .heading {
  background-color: #41AF43;
}
.vdos .heading {
  background-color: #FF8A00;
}
.sqaa .heading {
  background-color: #FF1F2D;
}
```

See the result on [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2dh2ery/).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do what you are trying to do is by using the `display: table` CSS properties.

[JS Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vyxh5vqu/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="heading table-cell">Notes</div>
    <div class="heading table-cell">Things To Know</div>
    <div class="heading table-cell">Videos</div>
    <div class="heading table-cell">Solved Question and Answer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">With our complete study notes, your homework is much easier.</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Things to know provides additional information on every topic which enhance the knowledge of  the students.</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Reference videos on each topic provides experimental ideas and develops interactive learning technique.</div>
    <div class="table-cell">With 100's of solved questions solved, now you can easily prepare your exam for free.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
  display: table;
}
.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.heading {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Here is an update](http://jsfiddle.net/vyxh5vqu/3/) with styling similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative using jquery. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lfgotdd/).

```
JQUERY

$('.parentheight').each(function(){
var maxdivheight = 0;
$('.childheight',this).each(function(){
  var divheight = $(this).height();
  // compare height
  if ( divheight > maxdivheight ) {
    maxdivheight = divheight;
  } else { }
});
// set all divs to max height
$('.childheight',this).height(maxdivheight);
});

HTML

<section class="notes-list-box parentheight">
    <div class="alignbox nn childheight">
    <div class="heading">Notes</div>
    <div class="boxdescription">With our complete study notes, your homework is much easier.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="alignbox ttn childheight">
    <div class="heading">Things To Know</div>
    <div class="boxdescription">Things to know provides additional information on every topic which enhance the knowledge of  the students.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="alignbox vdos childheight">
    <div class="heading">Videos</div>
    <div class="boxdescription">Reference videos on each topic provides experimental ideas and develops interactive learning technique.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="alignbox sqaa childheight">
    <div class="heading">Solved Question and Answer</div>
    <div class="boxdescription">With 100's of solved questions solved, now you can easily prepare your exam for free.</div>
  </div>
</section>

CSS

.alignbox {
  float: left;
  width: 24%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by setting everything to 100% height like so: http://jsfiddle.net/sur38w6e/

Your html was untouched.

```
.notes-list-box>div{
float:left;
width:120px;
background-color:yellow;
margin: 5px;
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
}

.heading{
  background-color:red;
}

.notes-list-box{
  background-color:green;
  overflow:auto;
  height:100%;
}

body,html{
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's the result that OP wanted. IMHO columns should have as low height as possible.

Comment: Yes it should have low height as possible .